# Failed to receive any response from server in android using Retrofit and PHP as backend

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Failed to receive body from  response. i used php as back end server in android using Retrofit . in my every project i used retrofit but this time i failed getting response body from server i don't know where is the problem.

I search all over the internet but i failed to get out myself from the problem. in below i put all of my code. Thanks you a lot in advance

> VideoApi.class

import java.util.List;

```
    import retrofit2.Call;
    import retrofit2.Retrofit;
    import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
    import retrofit2.http.GET;

    public interface VideoApi {
        String BASE_URL = "https://mozeloapp.in/ViddoApp/ViddoVideoRetrive.php/";

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        @GET(BASE_URL)
        Call<List<VideoModel>> getVideoLink();

    }
```

ModelClass.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class VideoModel {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("categoryId")
    @Expose
    private String categoryId;
    @SerializedName("categoryName")
    @Expose
    private String categoryName;
    @SerializedName("videoLink")
    @Expose
    private String videoLink;

    public VideoModel() {
    }

    public VideoModel(String id, String categoryId, String categoryName, String videoLink) {
        this.id = id;
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.videoLink = videoLink;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public String getVideoLink() {
        return videoLink;
    }

    public void setVideoLink(String videoLink) {
        this.videoLink = videoLink;
    }
}
```

> MainActivity.java

```
 private VideoApi videoApi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoApi = VideoApi.retrofit.create(VideoApi.class);
        Call<List<VideoModel>> call = videoApi.getVideoLink();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<VideoModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<VideoModel>> call, Response<List<VideoModel>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    for (VideoModel videoModel : response.body()){
                        String link = videoModel.getVideoLink();
                        Log.d("VIDEOLINK", "onResponse: "+link);
                    }
                }else {
                    Log.d("VIDEOLINK", "onResponse: "+"failed");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<VideoModel>> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.d("VIDEOLINK", "onResponse: "+t.getLocalizedMessage());

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exception? Also: I see the certificate is Let's encrypt. Some oldish phones do not have the authority in their truststore and thus, the authority needs to be added specifically. Have you conducted the experiments in the past with the same device?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be wrong in the attributes you parse. I expect that from this line:

```
Log.d("VIDEOLINK", "onResponse: "+link);
```

You get the output

```
"onResponse: null"
```

Correct your `SerializedName` definitions:

```
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String categoryName;
@SerializedName("link")
@Expose
private String videoLink;
```

I am basing my answer on what I see as response from your API.